# ActiveRecord execute raw transaction typecasting?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`

The results are not typecasted so they are all strings as an example
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).entries`

`=> [{"id" => "1", "length" => "120", "content" => "something"},{"id" => "2", "length" => "200", "content" => "blahblah"}]`

Is it possible to execute raw transactions in activerecord and return typecasted results?

Comment: AFAIK no. AR usually casts things using its knowledge of the schema rather than what the database tells it about the types of things, the result is that raw SQL gives you a bunch of strings because AR is too simpleminded to give you anything else. Cast the values yourself with the needed `to_i`, `to_f`, ... calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to [ORM](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) (Object relational mapping)

First of all, `connection.execute` will return a Mysql adapter where you can just iterate over the rows

You cant convert array of strings(the result you have) to ActiveRecord objects just like that ( I guess this is what you referred as typecasting)

What you can do is use `find_by_sql`.

**Ex:**

```
Blog.find_by_sql("select * from blog")
# => [#<Blog id: 1, name: "first blog", description: nil, record_status_id: 1>]
```

Using this method you can get ActiveRecord Objects fro raw SQL

Comment: I actually have a very complex query involving data from multiple data that I would like the output to be a hash. And using ORM is a bit cumbersome. I don't need objects. However, it would be nice to have typecasting otherwise I have to then manually change output to their supposed types.

Comment: I still couldnt get you, typecaste the results into what ?

Comment: can you explain your question with an input and ouput ?

Comment: From [{"id" => "1", "length" => "120", "content" => "something"},{"id" => "2", "length" => "200", "content" => "blahblah"}] to [{"id" => 1, "length" => 120, "content" => "something"},{"id" => 2, "length" => 200, "content" => "blahblah"}]

Comment: The database knows the Id and length are both integers however the query returns strings only. I was hoping that AR or another gem could execute raw query to typecast to its supposed types

Comment: for mysql I get the result like you said..no change of data types

Comment: Umm weird, I am using postgresql, maybe that is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Consider manifesting your SQL statement as a view, and creating a new record to interface with the view.

Here's a project where I'm backing AR with a view:
https://github.com/michaelkirk/household-account-mgmt/blob/develop/app/models/monthly_report.rb

```
class CreateMonthlyReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    sql = <<-SQL
      create view monthly_reports as
        select date_part('year', created_at) as year, date_part('month', created_at) as month, sum(purchase_amount) as purchases_amount, sum(investment_amount) as investments_amount
          from (
            select * from transactions
              left join
                (select id as purchase_id, amount as purchase_amount from transactions where credit = false)
                as purchases on transactions.id = purchases.purchase_id
              left join
                (select id as investment_id, amount as investment_amount from transactions where credit = true)
                as investments on transactions.id = investments.investment_id)
              as classified_transactions
          group by year, month
          order by year, month
    SQL

    execute(sql)
  end

  def down
    sql = <<-SQL
      drop view monthly_reports
    SQL

    execute(sql)
  end
```

Then, since you've abstracted your complexity into a database view, which for all AR's intents/purposes works like a table your model and controller look completely vanilla.

```
class MonthlyReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

  def time_period
    "#{month} #{year}"
  end

  def month
    MONTHS[self[:month] - 1]
  end

  def year
    self[:year].to_i
  end

end
```

Then you can do things like

```
class MonthlyReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @monthly_reports = MonthlyReport.all
  end
end
```

Note that because this is a DB view, you won't be able to do inserts. I'm not sure what would happen if you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *can* get results cast either as ActiveRecord objects (see the `find_by_sql` method [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql)) or as native Ruby types (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30948357/1103543)).