# Getting typed results from ActiveRecord raw SQL

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In Sequel, I can do:

```
irb(main):003:0> DB["select false"].get
=> false
```

Which returns a false boolean.  I'd like to be able to do something similar in ActiveRecord:

```
irb(main):007:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value "select false"
=> "f"
```

As you can see, it returns the string `"f"`. Is there a way to get a false boolean with ActiveRecord? (Similarly, I might be calling a function that returns a timestamptz, an array, etc -- I'd want the returned value to have the correct type)

My use case: I'm calling a database function, want to get back a typed result instead of a string.

Comment: Sequel is better than ActiveRecord at casting values based on metadata returned in the query. Maybe the new ActiveRecord under development will be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 6, `Person.connection.select_all(sql_query).to_a`

...will return an array of hashes whose values are type-casted. Example:

```
[{"id"=>12, "name"=>"John Doe", "vip_client"=>false, "foo"=> nil, "created_at"=>2018-01-24 23:55:58 UTC}]
```

If you prefer an `OpenStruct`, use Mike's suggestion:

`Person.connection.select_all(sql_query).to_a.map  {|r| OpenStruct.new(r) }`

If you prefer symbols as keys, call `map(&:symbolize_keys)` after `to_a`.

Answer (score 29):

While I have no doubt that Björn Nilsson's answer worked when he posted it, it is failing for me with Postgres `9.4` and PG gem version `0.18.2`.  I have found the following to work after looking through the PG gem documentation:

```
pg = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
@type_map ||= PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new(pg.raw_connection)

res = pg.execute("SELECT 'abc'::TEXT AS a, 123::INTEGER AS b, 1.23::FLOAT;")
res.type_map = @type_map
res[0]
# => {"a"=>"abc", "b"=>123, "float8"=>1.23}
```

Comment: I like this solution.  It also keeps the column names.  You know if there is a big performance hit for running PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new(pg.raw_connection) each time?  It seems to get all types for all columns in the DB...

Comment: `pg.raw_connection.type_map_for_results = PG::BasicTypeMapForResults.new(pg.raw_connection)` as the 2nd line also works. There is no need to assign *type_map* for an individual result in this case.

Answer (score 14):

Pretty ugly but does what you are asking for:

```
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.
select_all("select 1 as aa, false as aas, 123::varchar, Array[1,2] as xx")

# Breaks unless returned values have unique column names
res.map{|row|row.map{|col,val|res.column_types[col].type_cast val}}

# Don't care about no column names
res.map{|row|
  row.values.map.with_index{|val,idx|
    res.column_types.values[idx].type_cast val
  }
}
```

gives:

```
[[1, false, "123", [1, 2]]]
```

How it works:

```
res.column_types
```

returns a hash of columns names and Postgresql column types

Here is a pointer to how it works:
https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/fb8ac4f7b8487e4bb5c241dc0ba74da30f21ce9f/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/float.rb

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. Seems like there should be a `select_rows_typed` method or something in AR. It's nice to be able to get the raw string value if you care about performance, but for most things, you want to get back a typed result.

Comment: Glad it helped! I'm guessing the issue is that this is specific to PostgreSQL and maybe not general enough for active record. Also AR is generally primarily used for mapping tables to models so I guess this kind of stuff hasn't been worked on that much.

Comment: It seems that #type_cast has become a private method now. I had to update to: res.map{|row|row.map{|col,val|res.column_types[col].send(:type_cast, val)}}

Comment: You should use `type_cast_from_database` instead of `send(:type_cast`, found it here : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord/4.2.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/OID/Array

Comment: One can [create a handy concern for AR Result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329394/673826). This way you'd call `res.cast` or alike.

Answer (score 9):

Don't have enough reputation points to respond, but Bjorn's answer and associated replies are broken in Rails 5.  This works:

```
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
res.to_a.map{|o| o.each{|k, v| o[k] = res.column_types[k].cast v}}
```

Comment: This actually worked for me (once I corrected 'obj' to 'o') where none of the others did. My function was returning a postgres array in the form of '{1,2,3}' and this actually got the value cast into a rails array

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me (tried on both a simple and a complex query) on Rails 5.1.6. Would be neat with an ActiveRecord::Result extension that adds this as a method (e.g. `.with_types`)

Comment: I think you could skip `.to_a`

Comment: For some reason I prefer `res.to_a.map{|r| OpenStruct.new(r)}`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is the way, but you can create activerecord model without table with sort of fake column:

```
class FunctionValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.columns
    @columns ||= [];
  end

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(
      name.to_s,
      default,
      sql_type.to_s,
      null
    )
  end

  column :value, :boolean
end
```

And then you can run this:

```
function_value = FunctionValue.find_by_sql('select false as value').first
function_value.value
```

Comment: I was looking for something a bit more generic. I might be calling functions that return a timestamptz or an array or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in rails 5

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
results.rows.map{ |row| Hash[results.columns.zip(row)] }
```

Gives nice results

```
[{"person1"=>563, "person2"=>564, "count"=>1},
 {"person1"=>563, "person2"=>566, "count"=>5},
 {"person1"=>565, "person2"=>566, "count"=>1}]
```

Comment: This does not cast fancy types. I have a PostgreSQL *tstzrange* type. I end up having String instead of a range with this approach on Rails 5.2.