# ActiveRecord::Result returned from mysql backed `.select_all` not having type info

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to type cast the result from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all`, but type info seems to be empty. According to this [Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331778/getting-typed-results-from-activerecord-raw-sql), the type info can be derived by `result.column_types` at least when using postgres adapter. But when I run the same code with mysql adapter, I get nothing returned.

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(User.all.to_sql)
result.column_types #=> returns {} 
result.cast_value #=> returns uncasted values
```

I know there's something like this that casts the thing,

```
User.type_for_attribute('id').deserialize('100')
# => 100
```

But this won't work well when working with ActiveRecord::Result, because we don't know which column belongs to which ActiveRecord class (at least from the result).

**Question 1. Are there any easy ways to achieve type casting on ActiveRecord::Result?

I followed the source code a bit, and seems like mysql adapter isn't passing the type info when initialising the Result object. Below is how ActiveRecord::Result is initialised ([gh code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb#L39)),

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Result
    def initialize(columns, rows, column_types = {})
       @columns      = columns
       @rows         = rows
       @hash_rows    = nil
       @column_types = column_types
    end
    ...
```

And here's [ActiveRecord's mysql adapter code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/database_statements.rb#L34) and you can see it doesn't pass anything as the third argument, whereas, [postgres code does](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb#L89).

So I'm guessing type casting for mysql is done somewhere else.

**Question 2. Anybody knows where the magic for mysql is happening along with the normal ActiveRecord usage like `User.first.id`?**