# Postgres treat selected json_agg'regated string as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

In the following query(*), I am finding that `foo_ids` comes back as a string representation of the array. When I finally run `to_json` on my `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all` result, I see that it of course gets represented as a string in the resulting output.

```
SELECT
  bar.a,
  bar.b,
  bar.c,
  (
    SELECT JSON_AGG(DISTINCT foo_id)
    FROM foo
    WHERE bar.id = foo.bar_id
  ) AS foo_ids
FROM bar
```

Is there anything I can do to get the desired selection as an array into the final JSON output without having to modify the intermediate result?

(*) The query has been simplified for this question.

Comment: Maybe use `ARRAY_AGG` instead

Comment: @AbM I tried this already - it gives a different array notation output, but still string-wrapped e.g. `"{30,31}"`

Comment: It might be possible that I can cast the column to an array somehow, e.g. `'{1,1}'::int[]`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with help from @unabridged's answer to this question: [Getting typed results from ActiveRecord raw SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25331778/1090438).

I also used `array_agg` instead of `json_agg` to ensure the data would be an array to be later converted to JSON.

I came to the conclusion that there is no way around this, and that I just needed to find a suitable way of converting the types using ActiveRecord like so:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query)
  .to_a.map { |o| o.each { |k, v| o[k] = result.column_types[k].cast(v) } }
```

Where `query` would be the SQL string.

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all`? Can't you just use `Bar.joins(:foos).select('bar.a, bar.b, bar.c, array_agg(foo.id) as foo_ids').group(:id)`?

Comment: I'm deliberately avoiding using a model because it has been removed from the codebase - this code is for a migration